# Python Whois Issue

Tags: whois

Im trying to collect information on IP via whois within bash. 
However the output Im getting seems to be very different for example...

If I go to http://whois.domaintools.com/8.8.8.8 I get a ton of information. 
Like so,

```
NetRange:       8.0.0.0 - 8.127.255.255
CIDR:           8.0.0.0/9
NetName:        LVLT-ORG-8-8
NetHandle:      NET-8-0-0-0-1
Parent:         NET8 (NET-8-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Level 3 Parent, LLC (LPL-141)
RegDate:        1992-12-01
Updated:        2018-04-23
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/8.0.0.0

OrgName:        Level 3 Parent, LLC
OrgId:          LPL-141
Address:        100 CenturyLink Drive
City:           Monroe
StateProv:      LA
PostalCode:     71203
Country:        US
RegDate:        2018-02-06
Updated:        2018-02-22
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/LPL-141

OrgTechHandle: IPADD5-ARIN
OrgTechName:   ipaddressing
OrgTechPhone:  +1-877-453-8353 
OrgTechEmail:  
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/IPADD5-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: IPADD5-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   ipaddressing
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-877-453-8353 
OrgAbuseEmail:  
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/IPADD5-ARIN

NetRange:       8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
CIDR:           8.8.8.0/24
NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8
NetHandle:      NET-8-8-8-0-1
Parent:         LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1)
NetType:        Reallocated
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Google LLC (GOGL)
RegDate:        2014-03-14
Updated:        2014-03-14
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/8.8.8.0

OrgName:        Google LLC
OrgId:          GOGL
Address:        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway
City:           Mountain View
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94043
Country:        US
RegDate:        2000-03-30
Updated:        2018-10-24
Comment:        Please note that the recommended way to file abuse complaints are located in 
the following links. 
Comment:        
Comment:        To report abuse and illegal activity: https://www.google.com/contact/
Comment:        
Comment:        For legal requests: http://support.google.com/legal 
Comment:        
Comment:        Regards, 
Comment:        The Google Team
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/GOGL

OrgTechHandle: ZG39-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Google LLC
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgTechEmail:  
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ZG39-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE5250-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-253-0000 
OrgAbuseEmail:  
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE5250-ARIN
```

However, if I run whois 8.8.8.8 I just get :

```
 whois 8.8.8.8
[Querying whois.arin.net]
[whois.arin.net]

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2019, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#


#
# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
#     "n 8.8.8.8"
#
# Use "?" to get help.
#

Level 3 Parent, LLC LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1) 8.0.0.0 - 8.127.255.255
Google LLC LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8 (NET-8-8-8-0-1) 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
```

How can I get this level of information from whois CLI?

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer in your own post:

```
# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
#     "n 8.8.8.8"

...

Level 3 Parent, LLC LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1) 8.0.0.0 - 8.127.255.255
Google LLC LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8 (NET-8-8-8-0-1) 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
```

The last two lines show you that there are 2 blocks registered at ARIN that covers `8.8.8.8` and the two blocks of data you have through the provider you use at beginning of your message are the details of these two blocks.
Or else in your case:

```
whois -h whois.arin.net NET-8-0-0-0-1
```

and

```
whois -h whois.arin.net NET-8-8-8-0-1
```

Or consult ARIN's whois help with `whois -h whois.arin.net -- '-h'` which will show you among various stuff

> n Network address space

and

> + FULL output shows detailed display for EACH match

So if you do:

```
whois -h whois.arin.net -- 'n + 8.8.8.8'
```

you will get basically exactly the same output as your first example.

Comment: Thank you!  For anyone else having trouble getting MacOS's version of `whois` to work, the winning combination is `whois -S -h whois.arin.net "n + <target_ip>"`